# One to zero-or-one relationship: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is OFF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have two entities:

```
public class Subscription
{
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubscriptionError> SubscriptionErrors { get; set; }
}

public class SubscriptionError
{
    public int SubscriptionErrorId { get; set; }
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }

    public virtual Subscription Subscription { get; set; }
}
```

Originally, I defined the relationship between them as one-to-many in the `SubscriptionErrorMap` as follows:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.Subscription)
            .WithMany(t => t.SubscriptionErrors)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.SubscriptionId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I am using the following code for saving SubscriptionError:

```
context.SubscriptionErrors.Add(subscriptionError);
```

where `subscriptionError` is the entity and I am not explicitly setting the primary key field.

This used to work fine. But, when I changed this relationship to `one to zero-or-one`, it started to throw the following exception on saving:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'SubscriptionError' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

The new mapping is:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.Subscription)
            .WithOptional(t => t.SubscriptionError)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Is there something wrong with the mapping?

Comment: What is your code for saving. It may be that you need to set the key on `SubscriptionErrors` explicitly for updates.

Comment: Added the saving code to the question.

Comment: Shouldn't you be saving `Subscription` and not `SubscriptionErrors`

Comment: But why does it work fine when the relationship is one to many?

Comment: @NimishDavidMathew, What is your opinion about that answer ? did your problem resolved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

Remove the PK field `SubscriptionErrorId` and set `SubscriptionId` as both PK and FK for `SubscriptionError`.

Entities would now look like the following:

```
public class Subscription
{
     public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }

     public virtual SubscriptionError SubscriptionError { get; set; }
}

public class SubscriptionError
{
    [ForeignKey("Subscription")]
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Subscription Subscription { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seeing the DB's model script is something like below

```
CREATE TABLE Subscription(
    [SubscriptionId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    --[FieldName1] [nchar](100) NULL,
    --[FieldNameN] [nchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Subscription] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SubscriptionId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE SubscriptionError(
    [SubscriptionErrorId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SubscriptionId] [int] NULL,
    --[FieldName1] [nchar](100) NULL,
    --[FieldNameN] [nchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SubscriptionError] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SubscriptionErrorId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE SubscriptionError  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SubscriptionError_Subscription] FOREIGN KEY([SubscriptionId])
REFERENCES Subscription ([SubscriptionId]) 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SubscriptionError] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SubscriptionError_Subscription]
```

Which `[SubscriptionErrorId]` is key but it is not auto increment field
so for `one-to-many` relation model should be like below :

```
public partial class Subscription
{ 
    public Subscription()
    {
        SubscriptionErrors = new HashSet<SubscriptionError>();
    } 
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<SubscriptionError> SubscriptionErrors { get; set; }
}
```

and for `SubscriptionError`:

```
public partial class SubscriptionError
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int SubscriptionErrorId { get; set; } 
    public int? SubscriptionId { get; set; } 
    public virtual Subscription Subscription { get; set; }
}
```

That works like a charm but for `one-to-one` or `one-to-zero` relation 
that `SubscriptionError` for `Subscription` is not collection and the relation should be defined by fluent api like below:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Subscription>()
    .HasOptional(s => s.SubscriptionError)
    .WithRequired(ad => ad.Subscription);
```

and the models:

```
public partial class Subscription
{
    public Subscription()
    {
    }
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public virtual SubscriptionError SubscriptionError { get; set; }
}
public partial class SubscriptionError
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int SubscriptionErrorId { get; set; }
    public int? SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subscription Subscription { get; set; }
}
```

so please take a look at your DB's `SubscriptionError` and check out what properties set for `SubscriptionError` anyway in EF's conventions when an Id `pk` (SubscriptionErrorId ends with Id and EF interpret it as primary key) int property be found, it will configure that column as identity  which mean database generate value for the key property, for example the auto `SubscriptionErrorId` will be mapped to identity key automatically and there is no need to decorate it by `DatabaseGeneratedOption` explicitly but `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` is used here because that key should be generated by code pragmatically.

**about your problem** when we defined `one-to-one` relation this means that the child does not mean if it's parent does not exist for this reason the foreign key is primary key in this situation !!! for yours model for `SubscriptionError` mode the `SubscriptionId` prop is also key because of one to one or zero relation, if you look at the sample in **[here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)** there is no `PK` in `StudentAddress` anyway in you situation that you have `SubscriptionError` with auto generate `SubscriptionErrorId` if you don't define the `PK` you will got

> SubscriptionError: EntityType: EntitySet 'SubscriptionError' is based on type 'SubscriptionError' that has no keys defined.

if you define that column both as key with order like :

```
[Key, Column("SubscriptionErrorId", Order = 1)]
public int SubscriptionErrorId { get; set; } 
[Key, Column("SubscriptionId", Order = 2)]
public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
```

you will also get

> Entities in 'Model.SubscriptionError' participate in the 'Subscription_SubscriptionError' relationship. 0 related 'Subscription_SubscriptionError_Source' were found. 1 'Subscription_SubscriptionError_Source' is expected.'

**but if your model be something like below, defined `SubscriptionErrorId` as `Identity` and define `SubscriptionId` as key which `SubscriptionErrorId` is auto increment:**

```
public partial class SubscriptionError
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SubscriptionErrorId { get; set; } 
    [Key]
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; } 
    public virtual Subscription Subscription { get; set; }
}
```

then your code will work like a charm:

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    var se = new SubscriptionError()
    {
        FieldName1 = "Value",
        SubscriptionId = 1,//Parent key
        //SubscriptionErrorId is auto 
    };
    context.SubscriptionError1.Add(se);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But, this did not work for me.